# Ruby on Rails Sunspot solr condition on included association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I'm trying to search Products using solr and it's working well. Except that I want to restrict the suppliers, associated with Products by has_and_belongs_to_many, using the status field in Supplier model being 0 or 1.

My models are:

"Product.rb"

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :suppliers, :class_name => 'Company'

searchable do
    text :name
    text :brand
    text :description
end
```

"Company.rb"

```
attr_accessible :status

has_and_belongs_to_many :products
```

For search I'm using:

```
@search = Product.search(:include => :suppliers) do
  fulltext params[:s]
  with :status, 1   # This gives error as status is not a field in Product
end
```

How can I include only those suppliers with status 1?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the status in the searchable

```
searchable do
    text :name
    text :brand
    text :description
    boolean :status
end
```